# Pointwise convergence of Fourier Series to aperiodic function

Tags: convergence-divergence, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, uniform-convergence

The Fourier Series of $f(x)$ is said to be:
$$f(x) = \lim_{N \to \infty}\sum_{i=0}^{N}{(a_i\cos(\frac{2\pi}{P}ix)+b_i\sin(\frac{2\pi}{P}ix))}$$

Now it is said that you can obtain the belonging coefficients by integrating on both sides, from an arbitrary point $t$ to an arbitrary point $t + P$, and multiplying by cosines and sines of the different frequencies. This will result in zeroing out every term except one on the RHS, and rearrangement will yield the coefficient.

It is said that, if the function is $P$-periodic, then the series will converge to the function uniformly everywhere. But, it is also said that even though the function is not periodic, the series still converges uniformly on our chosen interval from $t$ to $t+P$.
(So it will sort of infinitely repeat an interval of the input function. And the idea behind the Fourier Transform is to let $P \nearrow \infty$ so that we can approximate aperiodic functions.)

I have taken a close look at the proof of pointwise convergence below:

https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/mathematics/dirichlet-kernel

You can get to the proof by searching for: "4.3 Methods of Convergence of Fourier Series"

The method of this proof is classical: it will involve proving that $\lim_{N \to \infty} \mid f(x) - S_N(x) \mid = 0$ by using the Dirichlet kernel and Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma.

What is not entirely clear for me, is from which part of the proof is it evident that the input function is required to be periodic? As far as I know, if you gained the coefficients by integrating from $t$ to $t+P$, then on this one single interval the series should still converge even if the function is aperiodic. And then how would you prove pointwise convergence at $x \in \left[t,t+P\right]$ to an aperiodic function?

Comment: Fix indices -$n$ or $i$?

Comment: @herbsteinberg yes thanks

Comment: Input function is not required to be periodic.  Series will give the original function only in the interval (t,t+P), and (as you observed) repeat outside.

Comment: @herbsteinberg Thanks for the reinforcement! Did you happen to look at the proof I reference? Does the proof also work for a nonperiodic function, if yes, where is it evident that x should be in the given interval? Or could you reference a more elaborate proof which clearly mentions how pointwise convergence works for an aperiodic function?

Comment: I think your "it is said" misstates the theorem.  Take for instance $f(x)=x$ on the interval $[0,1]$.  If you sketch the graphs of $S_N$, it should be clear that $S_N$ does not converge to $f$ uniformly on $[0,1]$, nor even on $(0,1)$.  What is true is that the Fourier series converges uniformly to $f$ on compact subsets of $(0,1)$.

Comment: @NateEldredge But it does not provide pointwise convergence for all x on the interval [0, 1] with the same coefficients?

Comment: @PatrikNusszer: What you get is pointwise convergence for all $x$ in $(0,1)$.  Note that $S_N(0) =S_N(1)$ by periodicity of sin and cos, so they cannot converge to both $f(0)$ and $f(1)$.

Comment: @NatedEldredge Thanks for drawing my attention to this, I did not know the conditions of uniform convergence. If you can, can you reference any pointwise convergence proof, where it is made clear that in case of an aperiodic function you don't get convergence outside the bounds of integration, which is from t to t+P? Or is it detectable from the proof I reference, I just could not realise it? I also have a Harvard version which is similar in technic: https://people.math.harvard.edu/~knill/teaching/math22b2019/handouts/lecture30.pdf

Comment: I think you are missing a basic point.  Outside the interval, the series converges to the copies of the function within the interval.  If the function is not periodic, the series will not match those parts (outside).

Comment: @herbsteinberg No I don't, that is exactly how I think about it. What I do not understand about these proofs, is how can they prove pointwise convergence for any x, without making it clear that the input function will only be approximated on the chosen interval (or else it will be repeated outside this interval). I dont see in which step of the proof it is evident that if x can be any number, then it is essential for the function to be periodic and the function can not be aperiodic (otherwise pointwise convergence to the function does not hold.)

Comment: If you look at the series cos and sin terms, replace x by y=x+nP for any integer n, you will see that the series converges to f(x), not f(y).

Comment: @herbsteinberg so the essential thing is, if the proof is shown to work, then f(x) must be periodic since the series itself is periodic? That is all?

Comment: Yes.  The series is periodic.  That's how Fourier series work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the apt remarks by Herb Steinberg and Nate Eldridge:

First, let me make clear that I am very sympathetic to this sort of question, as I was very confused by such things when I was learning about Fourier series and related matters. As in "how does the function know that we made it periodic?".

Then the computation of Fourier coefficients depends on the interval we restrict the function to. The corresponding expression in sines and cosines *by_its_nature* produces a periodic function, which agrees with the original function on the specified interval (more-or-less).

The convergence of the Fourier series to the original function (on the specified interval) is a non-trivial thing in itself. For many reasons, we often want *uniform* convergence, which is by no means promised. Even raw pointwise convergence is not guaranteed in much generality. Fortunately, these difficulties in our naive conception of "what we want" are not fatal, because it turns out that other forms of convergence (in $L^2$, or in Sobolev spaces) are often sufficient to justify computational conclusions.

Comment: So you basically repeat the fact that in order for the proofs I referenced to work it is essential that the input function is periodic given it can be approximated at any point by the periodic series? Your question "how the function knows that we made it periodic" is pretty much there.

Comment: Well, it depends what you mean precisely by "the input function", and what you mean by "the proofs to work". We can take an arbitrary function on $\mathbb R$, restrict our attention to that function on an interval $[a,b]$, and then conjure up another (related) function given by the original one on $[a,b]$, and by $b$-periodicity otherwise. The $[a,b]$ Fourier coefficients of the original one are those of the modified one... and the Fourier series "represents" _both_ on $[a,b]$, but just the modified one more generally.

Comment: EDIT: should be $b-a$ periodicity... sorry...

Comment: I guess the proof immediately implies that completing the proof means the LHS in the equation must be periodic the same way gaining the coefficients by integrating on both sides will guarantee only a result which will cause the series and the function to agree on their integrals on an interval and guarantees nothing as to pointwise convergence on the interval (since you would not be able to complete the coefficient proof without the integration), even though we started off by setting equal f(x) with its series.

Comment: Right, the basic set-up of Fourier series most-fundamentally determines the coefficients as certain (natural) integrals. The existence/convergence/sense of those integrals is the indispensable requirement to get started. Nothing is promised ahead-of-time about pointwise convergence... though, yes, we do have some theorems in this direction.

Comment: The way the problem arose was like "How the proof of convergence knows that it is allowed to work (allowed to make the difference of f(x) and its series approach zero) based on what is the original function?" Or like "Why is the proof so clever that it automatically adapts the original function from its original form to a periodic one?" or "How can be the proof be sure that I am not tricking it into showing the result for an aperiodic function?". It still bugs me hard that f(x) can be whatever, even though I see that the series is inevitably periodic because it can not do anything else.

Comment: The function we start with can indeed be anything at all, but then we take a fragment of it (the restriction to $[a,b]$), and make up a "new" function by making that restriction periodic. The computation of coefficients, by its nature, only refers really to that restricted-and-then-extended-by-periodicity function. If we are careful about language, there's no paradox about secret information being communicated, etc.

Comment: I was referring to the proof of pointwise convergence in this case, not to the proof of coefficients. That uses proving that $f(x)-S_N(x)$ tends to zero as N tends to infinity, using the Dirichlet kernel and Riemann Lebesgue Lemma. In that setup it is a precondition that $f(x)$ shall be periodic in order to able to complete the proof, I just do not see why, as I am able to complete the algebraic manipulations and show the difference tends to zero without knowing $f(x)$ should be periodic for this.

Comment: That argument with the Fourier-Dirichlet kernel refers to the value of the periodicized $f$ (or, equivalently, to the values at points in the interval to which the original $f$ is restricted). The usual line of argument involves some without-loss-of-generality simplifications that may obscure this fact.

Comment: where can I find a proof, or how may I modify the one I reference so that it does not have these simplifications? A proof in which it is clear that if $f(x)$ is not periodic then it only applies to the given interval? Is there any step in the middle of the proof that uses the fact that $f(x)$ should be periodic in order to proceed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128474/discussion-between-patrik-nusszer-and-paul-garrett).